# Perl's XML-Sig library adding dsig element to XML tags

Tags: xml, perl, digital-signature

I'm trying to sign a XML document using Perl's [XML::Sig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Sig) library. I based the code below on the example provided in its Meta CPAN example page. Using this code:

```
use XML::Sig;

my xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><foo ID="abc"><bar>123</bar></foo>';

my $pkey = '/path/to/X509/private.key';
my $cert = '/path/to/X509/certificate.pem';


my $signer = XML::Sig->new({
    key         => $pkey,
    cert        => $cert,
    x509        => 1,
    sig_hash    => 'sha256',
    digest_hash => 'sha256'
});

my $signedXml = $signer -> sign($xml);

print $signedXml;
```

Should produce something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <foo ID="abc">
        <bar>123</bar>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
              <Reference URI="#abc">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>9kpmrvv3peVJpNSTRycrV+jeHVY=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>
              HXUBnMgPJf//j4ihaWnaylNwAR5AzDFY83HljFIlLmTqX1w1C72ZTuRObvYve8TNEbVsQlTQkj4R
              hiY0pgIMQUb75GLYFtc+f0YmBZf5rCWY3NWzo432D3ogAvpEzYXEQPmicWe2QozQhybaz9/wrYki
              XiXY+57fqCkf7aT8Bb6G+fn7Aj8gnZFLkmKxwCdyGsIZOIZdQ8MWpeQrifxBR0d8W1Zm6ix21WNv
              ONt575h7VxLKw8BDhNPS0p8CS3hOnSk29stpiDMCHFPxAwrbKVL1kGDLaLZn1q8nNRmH8oFxG15l
              UmS3JXDZAss8gZhU7g9T4XllCqjrAvzPLOFdeQ==
            </SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <KeyValue>
                <RSAKeyValue>
                  <Modulus>
            1b+m37u3Xyawh2ArV8txLei251p03CXbkVuWaJu9C8eHy1pu87bcthi+T5WdlCPKD7KGtkKn9vq
            i4BJBZcG/Y10e8KWVlXDLg9gibN5hb0Agae3i1cCJTqqnQ0Ka8w1XABtbxTimS1B0aO1zYW6d+U
            Yl0xIeAOPsGMfWeu1NgLChZQton1/NrJsKwzMaQy1VI8m4gUleit9Z8mbz9bNMshdgYEZ9oC4bH
            n/SnA4FvQl1fjWyTpzL/aWF/bEzS6Qd8IBk7yhcWRJAGdXTWtwiX4mXb4h/2sdrSNvyOsd/shCf
            OSMsf0TX+OdlbH079AsxOwoUjlzjuKdCiFPdU6yAJw==
                  </Modulus>
                  <Exponent>Iw==</Exponent>
                </RSAKeyValue>
              </KeyValue>
            </KeyInfo>
       </Signature>
     </foo>
```

However, I'm getting this weird output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <foo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" ID="abc">
         <bar>123</bar>
            <dsig:Signature>
                <dsig:SignedInfo xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                        <dsig:Reference URI="#abc">
                            <dsig:Transforms>
                                <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </dsig:Transforms>
                        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                            <dsig:DigestValue>FHuo2WkVLRpa7bNfiojdVEHxa0nrhC1/uKoRjnkWJ94=
                            </dsig:DigestValue>
                        </dsig:Reference>
                </dsig:SignedInfo>
                <dsig:SignatureValue>kgp/+lPtErMFmtYIVJ+vpzzABLYOa0UEz6I7/LjHu/X+45vqpfVNZdLMjDzqShITA38LnNe+KuY/ qmXUplBXFQd26dP9opiAlh9rzS8YQ/yiWXcpQKoM2Ssam9c84ELUDy64Dw5NHXJUaFCVfyuwth/m Fju7J3r42KOvzl3YSAduqEVotDmyVx2WGv3/vr9MAkUfSrlc5PtQP9NU3et2lCVp+4B7wWD7vrDd w4Qnz7NYlc1xcbMtcHGNWHqzoWRInJgJG/wawRp8LRgeyxYFUTV7+U6gzbkCIbgy1CKGmfqkoWgJ vVO2kwwu7cKcZ6peFDdVSKriN/EpZOUn7uC2DA==
                </dsig:SignatureValue>
                <dsig:KeyInfo>
                    <dsig:X509Data>
                        <dsig:X509Certificate>MIIIGjCCBgKgAwIBAgIITEy4wqEVR0kwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwdDELMAkGA1UE BhMCQlIxEzARBgNVBAoTCklDUC1CcmFzaWwxNjA0BgNVBAsTLVNlY3JldGFyaWEg ZGEgUmVjZWl0YSBGZWRlcmFsIGRvIEJyYXNpbCAtIFJGQjEYMBYGA1UEAxMPQUMg VkFMSUQgUkZCIHY1MB4XDTIyMDgwMzE5MjkwMloXDTIzMDgwMzE5MjkwMlowggEn MQswCQYDVQQGEwJCUjELMAkGA1UECBMCU1AxDzANBgNVBAcTBlNVTUFSRTETMBEG A1UEChMKSUNQLUJyYXNpbDE2MDQGA1UECxMtU2VjcmV0YXJpYSBkYSBSZWNlaXRh IEZlZGVyYWwgZG8gQnJhc2lsIC0gUkZCMRYwFAYDVQQLEw1SRkIgZS1DTlBKIEEx MRYwFAYDVQQLEw1BUiBJTkZPUk1CQU5LMRkwFwYDVQQLExBWaWRlb2NvbmZlcmVu Y2lhMRcwFQYDVQQLEw4xNjY5NjA2MTAwMDE3NTFJMEcGA1UEAxNATUFYSU1VUyBE SVNUUklCVUlET1JBIERFIEVRVUlQQU1FTlRPUyBBVVRPTU9USVZPUzozNDMzMzIz MzAwMDEyODCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKtSXumD8s+I EutiXQuQqSiEXoIUvrsvgtOL4TbVlQTHwO/PXSitGdberioaYiQoC4ZKod48S9iJ 2X8gi+SUsrsvaVpNGEZFAbGHI0RD6NfUbuUZe3Ecq4NxJ7QxJNi34gkRHBrcOemd b8LtOtq6Ny0rujl6wvlNCQPFGGnjHCwzeO/qnGmiGLRedTr/xme2xD8wXwvyy1qR 1sYPzbUKCvAw74usAxN3aOGRwQgiMohsUysD3HcJyjCc5vLMFrgyRJ3aqujUXQj3 kOrfgo+w7fq2YG2RXjH0F7CpcKULXaNqCmmce9A764drrkq36Ty4cAXw3UnKWkw9 ZBk9UEYhItkCAwEAAaOCAvkwggL1MIGcBggrBgEFBQcBAQSBjzCBjDBVBggrBgEF BQcwAoZJaHR0cDovL2ljcC1icmFzaWwudmFsaWRjZXJ0aWZpY2Fkb3JhLmNvbS5i ci9hYy12YWxpZHJmYi9hYy12YWxpZHJmYnY1LnA3YjAzBggrBgEFBQcwAYYnaHR0 cDovL29jc3B2NS52YWxpZGNlcnRpZmljYWRvcmEuY29tLmJyMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAw HwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUU8ul5HVQmUAsvlsVRcm+yzCqicUwcAYDVR0gBGkwZzBlBgZg TAECASUwWzBZBggrBgEFBQcCARZNaHR0cDovL2ljcC1icmFzaWwudmFsaWRjZXJ0 aWZpY2Fkb3JhLmNvbS5ici9hYy12YWxpZHJmYi9kcGMtYWMtdmFsaWRyZmJ2NS5w ZGYwgbYGA1UdHwSBrjCBqzBToFGgT4ZNaHR0cDovL2ljcC1icmFzaWwudmFsaWRj ZXJ0aWZpY2Fkb3JhLmNvbS5ici9hYy12YWxpZHJmYi9sY3ItYWMtdmFsaWRyZmJ2 NS5jcmwwVKBSoFCGTmh0dHA6Ly9pY3AtYnJhc2lsMi52YWxpZGNlcnRpZmljYWRv cmEuY29tLmJyL2FjLXZhbGlkcmZiL2xjci1hYy12YWxpZHJmYnY1LmNybDAOBgNV HQ8BAf8EBAMCBeAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMEMIHNBgNV HREEgcUwgcKBIGZyYW5jaXNjby5iYXJjZWxsb3NhZHZAZ21haWwuY29toDgGBWBM AQMEoC8ELTIxMTIxOTY2MDg0NzUxMDY4OTcwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw MDAwMKAwBgVgTAEDAqAnBCVGUkFOQ0lTQ08gQ0FSTE9TIERPUyBTQU5UT1MgQkFS Q0VMTE9ToBkGBWBMAQMDoBAEDjM0MzMzMjMzMDAwMTI4oBcGBWBMAQMHoA4EDDAw MDAwMDAwMDAwMDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAEGcTeHal+ZqMse5zRXNDVO2T AAEWdOEfF4ssR0H67+R0KFy0RJ6NQa7QwnwHwaymw3TWd+lcRwEmp//6+v0xmBYm 7SiHjgsvVVZdC9WIN51BhskXZJltX+g8uTv1BafZ93YcEJiDJlj0Ng3GSwMOPg80 FXqjtAml5uas8KV2jI5r5Pm3gM2F+tbGFB8ybb4HgQfdvtUexgN/gTT+Mp4y9UsQ znuIu1XBNQHWSaYT1BKLh/cAdrE5hNwdwYkSuvHeiA20ak2m4fmdH8rhMsWHOtua kUh6fpoQCJXjJr5wxMD40boFSQQHdEasSRBPKOXNIbmmRWBVE9RhV+xxIwPDuZY+ E8W3H0mdOtzgXLgj/9y31jMNiQCymZ6MUxUJfwqIecOQsCVunREOPFD/u8fuIX+3 gpbcQudVTtD0duZMO5Uqa2z6hzMXuLR1/og4TnZoKJ4HrFijt5vrNKxIiJKDd9zz qOqFfvPOQ8AaBxmYfYzcn7V4NYSrU7wliGl92vdD1ZUC2HsgNzwAjEbI+Je+yWSM ria3Vr+f3X3qvoiARpZ7AuhpvUpVCdl0Khb7FlqFqfjebUZvvqqu2aREPmdPsagT DIu4BesHL8JIUs8nKEEqApYTHQukxMSq5Ixind9ZY8eaB69PqVO5a0qqfQxvOUwA AoF8N+KW4C8r5OvN6Mw= 
                    </dsig:X509Certificate>
                </dsig:X509Data>
            </dsig:KeyInfo>
        </dsig:Signature>
     </foo>
```

The `foo` tag is being marked with a `dsig` element, and every other element references it afterwards. This is causing problems because it alters the structure of the document I'm expected to sign, making it fail its structure validation.  Why is this happening? And how can I remove this `dsig`?

Edit: Corrected typos in the example code

Comment: Are you not familiar with xml namespaces?

Comment: Those are just two equivalent ways of creating the necessary `{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature` elements

Answer (score 4):

I maintain XML::Sig.  As above dsig is the namespace that is required for xml signatures.  It can be ds: in some cases but you need to set the namespace in your application to the prefix that you want to use.

You can verify the doc that is created with:

```
xmlsec1 verify --verbose --lax-key-search --id-attr:ID "foo" --pubkey-cert-pem t/rsa.cert.pem --untrusted t/intermediate.pem --trusted-pem t/cacert.pem text.xml 
Verification status: OK
SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1
Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0
```

BTW, there was a typo in your example:

```
use XML::Sig;

my $xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><foo ID="abc"><bar>123</bar></foo>';

my $pkey = 't/rsa.private.key';
my $cert = 't/rsa.cert.pem';


my $signer = XML::Sig->new({
    key         => $pkey,
    cert        => $cert,
    x509        => 1,
    sig_hash    => 'sha256',
    digest_hash => 'sha256'
});

my $signedXml = $signer -> sign($xml);

print $signedXml;
```

I referenced the private key and cert in the XML::Sig git repo:

```
perl -I blib/lib test.pl > text.xml
```

Comment: Also, if you are using perl review how namespaces are handled:

https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-XML-Sig/blob/7c035b231646163e0abe00ff2d7a8759ae4bf5aa/lib/XML/Sig.pm#L471

Feel free to log an issue at https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-XML-Sig if you think it is warranted

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried sending the XML signed this way, the other end refused this format - it's a government interface and they require the namespace declaration to be done like in my first example - in the tag Signature. In the end, a colleague mananged to sign our document manually.

Comment: See comment on ikegami's answer

Answer (score 3):

> *it alters the structure of the document I'm expected to sign*

It does not.

```xml
<foo>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      ...
   </Signature>
</foo>
```

is identical to

```xml
<foo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <dsig:Signature>
      ...
   </dsig:Signature>
</foo>
```

Elements are identified not just by their names; they are identified by a combination of both their namespace and their name. I'll use the `{namespace}name` notation going forward.

The above snippets create a `{}foo` element with a `{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature` child element. The structure is identical.

The first snippet changes the default namespace to achieve this. The second uses a prefix. But they are identical.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, but in my case this doesn't help me. Even though both are technically 'identical', the second method won't work for me, as I'm trying to sign a document to be sent to a government application, and the 2nd method is considered invalid - they do not accept that namespace declaration on the data being transmitted. The very reason we picked this library was because the example they provide in their CPAN page matches what the government requested

Comment: It sucks when someone says they accept XML, but they don't

Comment: You could try using the pull request in https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-XML-Sig/pull/44 from https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-XML-Sig/tree/fix_namespace_moved-2023-02-04 It moves the namespace from foo to the Signature

Answer (score 0):

So if you apply the pull request in https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-XML-Sig/pull/44 from https://github.com/perl-net-saml2/perl-XML-Sig/tree/fix_namespace_moved-2023-02-04. It will result in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo ID="abc"><bar>123</bar><dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <dsig:SignedInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <dsig:Reference URI="#abc">
                        <dsig:Transforms>
                            <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </dsig:Transforms>
                        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <dsig:DigestValue>FHuo2WkVLRpa7bNfiojdVEHxa0nrhC1/uKoRjnkWJ94=</dsig:DigestValue>
                    </dsig:Reference>
            </dsig:SignedInfo>
            <dsig:SignatureValue>kmE9L+ha8hbmBLg2Lb7h1k+L3YhsUC9J+nER3HDNXJ+5fHhwj86gZjzWNYO49DDqTIHSzI6zFEbD
XkLCldzuzcYfNACzPhZOW9Vf3kPuoQgZvCVtgUl1bliRJsdprdM7W7/9YZPJwYgxK9chj09v16/I
gY3HTe9vvCFGpe+04UTr7teKpNsuYhUHV2juuhhZq8cYE18nbd1bSLkHssMf+Q61nWBtvH+30Ke4
/P3NADK85VMTgu1XZ/JO0h9aIy30itij3UERjKsEKggaf6S7Exw48muzam3OmL7bDYlvRLJd7cYs
7Oxtg0tQwN0x42MHh8pkBon+PhsnWk/ko7yW4A==
</dsig:SignatureValue>
            <dsig:KeyInfo><dsig:X509Data><dsig:X509Certificate>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</dsig:X509Certificate></dsig:X509Data></dsig:KeyInfo>
        </dsig:Signature></foo>
```